# Vector coefficient based on similarity

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

I've been looking for a solution to create a recommendation system based on vectors similarity. Basically, i have a few vectors per user for example:

```
User1: [0,3,7,8,5] , [3,5,8,2,4] , [1,5,3,9,4]
User2: [3,1,6,7,9] , [2,4,1,3,8] , [7,8,3,3,1]
```

For every vector i need to calculate a coefficient and based on that coefficient differentiate a vector from another. I've found formulas that would calculate coefficients based on similarity of 2 vectors which i don't really want that.I need a formula that would calculate a coefficient per vector and then i do some other calculations with those coefficients.Are there any good formulas for this?Or maybe use those vectors in a matrix and do some calculations there? Thanks

Comment: Hi! Right now, it is unclear how to approach your question: it is difficult to give a good solution without knowing for what kind of applications these "coefficients" will be used. Could you include an example calculation you want to do to clarify what you're aiming for? Also, what do these vectors represent?

Comment: Basically, every vector represents some options chosen by some user.If user1 has [0,5,4,3,2] let's say the coefficient would be 18.Than user 2 has[4,2,1,5,8] let's say the coefficient would be 23. Based on those 2 values i would knew that those 2 users like different things.So, i'm looking for a formula that would help me calculate that coefficient number which should at least have some precision cause otherwise i would just do a mean and that would not help me at all.Also, i don't want to calculate a coefficient between 2 vectors...but i want to have one per vector.

Comment: The thing is, you can't "convert" something higher-dimensional (i.e., if your vectors have $n$ entries, the dimension is $n$) to a one-dimensional number (that is, the coefficient) without loosing some information along the way. That is, there will always be two vectors that are different but produce the same coefficient, no matter the algorithm. So, why don't you operate on the vectors themselves? To see if two vectors are equal, for example, just compare each of the coefficients one-to-one.

Comment: I don't really need it to be 100% precise:( i just wanted something that would be worth using and not doing something like a mean:(Do you know any formulas that might be worth looking into?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you mean by "worth doing". If you need this algorithm to use it in a computer program, you shouldn't worry about it being "worth doing"; operating directly on vectors will probably always be sufficiently fast. By the way, notice that the mean won't do in any case: the vectors $(1,3,5)$ and $(2,3,4)$ are different but have the same mean.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to explain it but that's what i was saying that the mean would not do any justice.Are there any other formulas that by having values like you said (1,3,5) and (2,3,4) would give me different results?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84246/discussion-between-anakhand-and-truica-sorin).